# How can return value be modified?

Tags: c, gdb, low-level, gsoap

I have a routine calling `gSoap` API function `soap_malloc`. But the program gives me a `segmentation fault` whenever I try to access the memory allocated by `soap_malloc`. When I use `gdb` to debug it. I find that inside `soap_malloc`, return value stored in register `%rax` is `0x7fffec0018f0`. But on return, `%rax` changed to `0xffffffffec0018f0`. Only the lower 32-bit was retained, the higher 32-bit all changed to `1`. And that lead to accessing an address which is quite high, therefore caused the routine stopped. Thanks for you all to give me any ideas on how can this be happening. I'm running my multi-thread program in `Ubuntu12.04 x86-64`.

This is how I call it:

```
void *temp = soap_malloc(soap, 96);
```

And this is the `soap_malloc` implementation(only that `else` part is executed, and macro `SOAP_MALLOC` is just passing the second argument to `malloc`, `SOAP_CANARY` is constant `0xC0DE`):

```
#ifndef SOAP_MALLOC         /* use libc malloc */
# define SOAP_MALLOC(soap, size) malloc(size)
#endif

#ifndef SOAP_CANARY
# define SOAP_CANARY (0xC0DE)
#endif

void* soap_malloc(struct soap *soap, size_t n)
{ register char *p;
  if (!n)
    return (void*)SOAP_NON_NULL;
  if (!soap)
    return SOAP_MALLOC(soap, n);
  if (soap->fmalloc)
    p = (char*)soap->fmalloc(soap, n);
  else
  { n += sizeof(short);
    n += (-(long)n) & (sizeof(void*)-1); /* align at 4-, 8- or 16-byte boundary */
    if (!(p = (char*)SOAP_MALLOC(soap, n + sizeof(void*) + sizeof(size_t))))
    { soap->error = SOAP_EOM;
      return NULL;
    }
    /* set the canary to detect corruption */
    *(unsigned short*)(p + n - sizeof(unsigned short)) = (unsigned short)SOAP_CANARY;
    /* keep chain of alloced cells for destruction */
    *(void**)(p + n) = soap->alist;
    *(size_t*)(p + n + sizeof(void*)) = n;
    soap->alist = p + n;
  }
  soap->alloced = 1;
  return p;
}
```

This is the definition of `SOAP_NON_NULL`:

```
static const char soap_padding[4] = "\0\0\0";
#define SOAP_NON_NULL (soap_padding)
```

**Updates(*2013-03-12*)**
I explicitly declared `soap_malloc` as returning `void *` and the problem solved. Previously, the returned value is truncated to `int` and the sign bit `1` was extended when assigning the result to `void *temp`.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code example that reproduces this problem?

Comment: In some places you use **soap_malloc** in others you use **SOAP_MALLOC**.  What is the definition of **SOAP_MALLOC** or is that part of the gSoap library?

Comment: @Jere I describe `SOAP_MALLOC` is a macro which just passing the second argument to `malloc`. Sorry for that, I'll edit them into the code body.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis where else do you think can cause this problem? I mean, I use a `void *` variable to store the returned value by `soap_malloc` which is also of type `void *`. `%rax` stays `0x7fffec0018f0` until `soap_malloc` returns.

Comment: @Jere Yes, it is part of gSoap library.

Comment: I compiled and printed calls to this code (using MinGW G++) and did not see any errors.  Out of curiosity, what platform/os version/compiler are you using?

Comment: @Jere I put a explicit `extern void *soap_malloc(struct soap *, size_t)` in the file, and the problem solved.`The return value is indeed truncated. I will edit the question once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the calling code have a proper prototype for the `soap_malloc()` function in scope?

It seems the `void *` is being converted to `int`, i.e. the default return type. This happens if the function hasn't been properly declared.

Comment: sorry, I should have put the calling code above `soap_malloc`. I just used a `void *temp` to stored the return value.

Comment: @leowang Not sure I understand your correction ... That doesn't matter. If you call plain old `malloc()` *without* including the header like this: `void *p = malloc(1024)`, you *will*  get an `int`-sized result. The type on the left-hand side of the `=` doesn't matter.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't get it. Anything wrong with `malloc`? What do you mean by `the header`?

Comment: Forgot to mention that even if I use a pointer of structure to cast the returned value of `soap_malloc`, the higher 32 bits still changed to `1`

Comment: What leowang is saying is somewhere you need have a extern declaration for the function **malloc** that defines it like you would find in the **stdlib.h** header file:  **extern void * malloc(size_t);**.  If you do not have this somewhere the compile may be assuming **extern int malloc()** which would result in your code assuming an integer is being returned not a void pointer which could be the cause of your truncation.